# Bit-operation OR vs addition

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

I am reading an uint16 from a sensor connected to an raspberry (arm). I convert the data from little endian to big endian via:

```
// result = 0A 0B
// 0B 00 | 00 0A
(result << 8) | (result >> 8);
```

So 0A 0B is 0B 0A afterwards.

But I also saw people using this:

```
(result << 8) + (result >> 8);
```

Is there any advantage of using the addition? My guess is, there is no really advantage, it is just a bit slower.

There is a big difference when it comes to sum two numbers for example:

```
EF10 = 0FF0 + 00FF != 0FF0 | 00FF = 0FFF
```

Maybe I answered my own question already but it would be nice, if someone could evaluate. Would not be the first time I am tricking myself.

Comment: Are you only asking about the advantage, or also about the difference? That last part doesn't really seem like a question..

Comment: Mainly about the advantage. I think I know the difference even if I could not explain it unambiguously. The addition should use a carry bit to sum while or just combines.

Comment: in general, I'd use bit operators for bit operations and use arithmetic operators for arithmetic operations, even if they sometimes equate and modern chips are quite efficient in terms of execution cycles.

Comment: why do you need to mask it with `& 0xFF00`? Only zero bits will shit in. Just do `(result << 8) | (result >> 8)`

Comment: @Pynchia thanks for pointing out. This is a thing I was wondering about myself a few days ago but forgot it. It is copied from my old code without thinking about it.

Comment: It makes a difference when *result* is a signed integer.  Right-shifting it is implementation-defined, using | will however invariably produce nonsense.  It makes no difference at all when it is an unsigned integer, a modern processor executes an ADD as fast as an OR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference (or advantage, at least not on modern processors) if the bits being combined aren't overlapping (in other words, the mask on the left-hand side has zeros for all bits set by the right-hand side, and vice versa)

The code shown here:

```
// result = 0A0B0C0D 0E0F0A0B
// 0E0F0A0B 00000000 | 00000000 0A0B0C0D
((result << 8) & 0xFF00) | (result >> 8);
```

is a little confusing - the comment seems to imply that it's a 32-bit value, but the calculation implies a 16-bit `result`

You will get different results for example if you do something like this:

```
value |= 128;
```

vs

```
value += 128;
```

when `value` already has the bit 7 set.

Note that at least in clang:

```
#include <cstdint>

uint32_t func1(uint32_t x)
{
    return (x >> 8) | ((x << 8) & 0xFF000000);
}

uint32_t func2(uint32_t x)
{
    return (x >> 8) + ((x << 8) & 0xFF000000);
}
```

The exact same code is generated:

```
_Z5func1j:                              # @_Z5func1j
    movl    %edi, %eax
    shrl    $8, %eax
    shll    $8, %edi
    andl    $-16777216, %edi        # imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000
    leal    (%rdi,%rax), %eax
    retq

_Z5func2j:                              # @_Z5func2j
    movl    %edi, %eax
    shrl    $8, %eax
    shll    $8, %edi
    andl    $-16777216, %edi        # imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000
    leal    (%rdi,%rax), %eax
    retq
```

Comment: yea your right. I am currently working with a sensor which delivers 32bit. sorry for that. Edited it. But I am quite unsure if I understand your example.

Comment: whay do `|` and `+` generate **exactly** the same code? These are different operations and usually yield different results: 0x03 + 0x02 = 0x05, 0x03|0x02 = 0x03

Comment: @Mats Petersson I do understand your example now. Also thank your for the assembly code. It is very interesting.

Comment: @DrKoch: Because the compiler realizes that the bits are NOT overlapping, and can generate "better" code with the `leal` instruction than with the `orl` instruction (don't ask me exactly what is "better" here, and it may well be an arbitrary choice)

Comment: Thinking a little more about it, I think the main advantage in "knowing that this is the same as an ADD" is that the compiler may be able to do more clever things when addressing when the result is used for indexing into an array, e.g. `arr[(x >> 8) | ((x << 8) & 0xFF000000)]` would be awkward when using `or`, but much easier when using `add`.

Answer (score 3):

Using bitwise or `|` makes it clear what is the intention to who reads the code, and that's the important point.

I would be surprised of speed differences between the two approaches.

Even better would be:

```
x = (x << 8) | (x >> 8);
```

because there is no need mask the left part (as incoming bits are zeros).

In case of a signed integer instead what is coming in when performing a right-shift operation on negative values is implementation dependent, therefore portable code should use

```
x = (x << 8) | ((x >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

to make it clear that a byte-swap operation is requested.

Comment: Note that `x` is `uint16` (rather than the standard `uint16_t`) in the question.  Your observations are generally valid, but almost certainly not critical for the context of the question.