# Is P1DIR |= (BIT0 | BIT6); and P1DIR |= BIT0 + BIT6; identical expressions?

Tags: c, expression, boolean-logic, xor, msp430

Yeah. I would like to know this. programming on my new msp430g2553 and both seems to work. The first one is from an online tutorial and the second one is what I had already put in my code and seems to work...

Are they identical?

UPDATE

BIT0 = 0x01
BIT6 = 0x04

Comment: they're the same if the two operands don't have any overlap bits, because in that case no carry is done. In that case `a | b` is equivalent to `a ^ b` and `a + b`. [Bit-operation OR vs addition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31097574/995714), [what is the difference between logical OR operation and binary addition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36329984/995714), [Bitwise-OR vs Adding Flags](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/23852/98103),

Comment: I guess it kinds of answers my question yea. But bottomline, when it comes to adresses, the first alternative would be better? Otherwise one might set some bits in vain if there is a carry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, yes they are the same. The same can't be said for an expression where you have more than 2 'bits' or where the 2 'bits' are the same.

Assuming `BIT0 = 00000001 and BIT6 = 01000000`

Then `BIT0 | BIT6 = 01000001 and BIT0 + BIT6 = 01000001`

But if we were using the same 'bits' twice ..

```
BIT0 | BIT0 = 00000001
```

BUT

```
BIT0 + BIT0 = 00000010
```

Answer (score 0):

If `BIT0` and `BIT6` are single bit constants, then there's no difference.

Comment: if they're single bit constants and `BIT0 == BIT6` then there would be a significant difference

Comment: I bow to your superior pedantry

Comment: I updated the question with the values. Basiically what I hear is it is the same because they don't share any bits? aka BIT0 & BIT & == 0